# HTML video controls not autohiding in firefox

Tags: javascript, html, html5-video

I have the following code that auto focuses the video when the page loads, and also registers the "F" key to toggle full screen of the video.

```html
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>Example</title>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            document.addEventListener("keypress", function onPress(event) {
                if (event.key.toLowerCase() === "f") {
                    const video = document.getElementById("video_player");

                    if (document.fullscreenElement) {
                        document.exitFullscreen();
                    } else {
                        if (video.requestFullscreen) video.requestFullscreen();
                    }
                }
            });

            function setupVideo() {
                let video = document.getElementById('video_player');
                video.focus();
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    
    <body onload="setupVideo();">
        
        <div class="wrapper">
            <video id="video_player" controls width="950" height="320">
                <source src="https://archive.org/download/Popeye_forPresident/Popeye_forPresident_512kb.mp4"/>
            </video>

        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

The issue is on Firefox (88.0.1), if you load the page, press "F" then "SPACE" to full screen and play the video, the controls don't auto-hide. This works as expected in chrome. I'm wondering if there's a special case I need to handle for it to work correctly in Firefox.

This is a very specific issue and will only occur if these exact actions are taken: Press F, Press space, and do not move the mouse. If you move the mouse at any point, it will auto hide.

(The video link was taken from this site: https://html.com/tags/video/ just giving credit )

Comment: Works fine here on FF 88.0.1 on macOS

Comment: I should probably be a bit more specific. It only doesn't auto hide if you do F then space and don't move your mouse at all. If you move your mouse it will auto hide.

Comment: Still works fine for me, the controls don't show at all if I don't move the mouse. And it's better to add clarification in the question itself, people may not read the comments

Comment: I see the problem on FF on Windows 10.

Comment: @Kaiido perhaps the os matters? I've added the clarification to the questions. Thanks.